# p:dataTable sorting Time

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a PrimeFaces DataTable like so:

```
<p:dataTable
        id="datatable_current_month_timesheets"
        value="#{timesheetBean.currentMonthTimesheets}" var="item">
    <p:column headerText="starttimeDate" sortBy="#{item.starttime}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.starttime}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEE, dd.MM.yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="starttimeTime" sortBy="#{item.starttime}"> //how to sort this?
        <h:outputText
            value="#{item.starttime}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="timeGap" sortBy="#{item.starttime}"> //how to sort this?
        <h:outputText
            value="#{timesheetBean.calculateTimeGap(item)}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The first column get sortet right since its get sorted by date and it doesn't make me any problems. 
The second column however has basically the same values as the first one BUT only the Time in Hours:Minutes.
The third column makes some calculations with the time and also fetches Time.
Since I dont save these values I dont know how to sort this by time!

Example would be 12:00 comes after 07:00 and before 14:35.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds to me as you need to use a custom sortFunction on the p:column

Comment: but how would I sort things if the value is dynamically generated? can I sort without specifying "sortBy" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
<p:column headerText="starttimeTime" sortBy="#{item.starttime}" sortFunction="#{timesheetBean.customSort}">
```

and

```
public int customSort(Object o1, Object o2) {
    Date d1 = (Date) o1;
    Date d2 = (Date) o2;

    // compare d1 and d2 anyway you like and return -1, 0 or 1

}
```

What you put in `sortBy` decides what you receive as method arguments. So if your calculations involves other properties besides the date just transfer the whole item with `sortBy="#{item}"` and cast the arguments correctly in above method.